Producing Excel timeline data
I have a table with about 4,000 entries. For each one I have an identifier and a start and end time. The data represents trains running for a given day.
I would like to produce a minute per minute count of running trains, and visualise that with a graph to easily see where the busiest times of the day are, and what the peak number of running trains looks like.
I've made a mess. I've got 1,440 columns, for each one minute increment for a 24 hour period; and I have over 4,000 rows. For all intersections I have a formula such as the following.
=IF( AND( given_minute >= start_time, given_minute <= end_time), 1, 0)

Where given_minute is the value of the minute column and start_time and end_time are row values.
I shouldn't be surprised for the Excel abuse, I have in one sheet 1,440 x 4,000 = 5.7M formulas running!
I got what I needed (barely), but I'd love for someone to share a better way of doing this, I'd love to learn a less brute force way!
Thanks


You only really need one formula for each minute interval.

Create a list of minute intervals
Name your Min and Max columns to make the formulas easier
Next to each time interval enter the following formaula

=COUNTIFS(MinRange,"<="&F2,MaxRange,">="&F2)
Sample:


So good. Although I don't get to produce a visual showing lines for each train, overlapping with others.

@Daniel If you add a column with the trip duration, you can use a stacked bar chart using only the departure time and the trip duration, then use "No Fill" for the departure time bars. See here

wonderful thank you !
